# extend Ract Pure Component with generic Props Type and State Type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, extends, generic-type-argument

```
// componet A
interface IPropsA {
  propsForA: boolean;
}

interface IStateA {
  isSleeping: boolean;  
};

class A<P extends IPropsA, S extends IStateA> extends React.PureComponent<P, S> {
    doStaff() {
      this.setState({ isSleeping: false });
    }
}

// componet B
interface IPropsB extends IPropsA {
   propsForB: string; 
};
interface IStateB extends IStateA{
  isWorking: boolean;  
};

class B extends A<bProps, bState> {
    doStaff() {
      this.setState({ isSleeping: false, isWorking: true });
    }
}
```

ts compiler showing error

```
Class 'A<P, S>' incorrectly extends base class 'PureComponent<P, S>'.
Types of property 'state' are incompatible.
Type 'IStateA' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S>'.
```

What is the correct way to extend the component A with extra properties in IStateB, so the component B would work?

My goal here is inherited every thing the component A has, and extend more functionality in B.

Comment: How do you get this error? It cannot be replicated, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-alcynf

Comment: is it not the runtime error, its from ts compiler,  with ts version you are using? Mine is "typescript": "2.6.2", "@types/react": "16.0.35",

Comment: Stackblitz outputs compiler errors, too, but there's none. You can check package versions in sidebar. Consider providing a way to replicate it - a repo, etc.

Comment: try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pddtt9?file=index.tsx , you can see the complain from ts